# Proving the continuity of the power series of logarithim

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, power-series

The Original question was from Understanding analysis - Abbott: Exercise $6.5.1$

This is the original question

Consider the function $g$ defined by the power series
$$g(x) = x − \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}....$$
(a) Is $g$ defined on $(−1, 1)$? Is it continuous on this set?

The first part showing it is defined is completely fine for me.
I had trouble dealing with the second part.
My first Idea is to show uniform convergence of the series but the endpoint is unbounded so it is not uniformly convergent. So I can't Apply term by term continuity theorem. So I tried the definition of continuity. But that still didn't work because of the divergence around
$-1$

I haven't started the chapter of taylor series tho so I should pretend that I don't know this is the power series for logarithm

Thanks

Comment: The function is continuous on every $[-1+\varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon]$. This suffices to show that it is continuous on $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: Do you mean the infinite series? Or just the finite sum written for $g(x)$?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes it should have been an infinite series. I forgot the dots